Why Allah is not helping me with very little wish
Assalamo Alaikum! Alhumdulillah, I am a muslim girl who loves her religion and a strong believer in ALLAH and His actions. I will not say that I am very religious because I have done sins, made mistakes all my life like any other human being would do however, I am someone who would recognise her flaws and do try to work on them. I try to say my prayers regularly and would try to avoid doing sins as much as possible.
I used to have very thick and long beautiful hair, clear skin etc but in the past few years, I noticed extreme hair loss and extreme acne on my face. This change was rather a sudden thing, I consulted doctors but there is nothing to worry about or any health issue. My hair is so thinning that I feel I’m going bald and might never be able to recover. I am not married yet and I feel I have become so ugly that no one would want to marry me, even if someone does, they surely will not be able to live with a bald wife for long.
I believe more in Allah than science or medicines, in research, it says that hair loss is permanent and irreversable. However, I didn’t believe in it and decided that I will seek Allah’s help as there is nothing impossible for Him. And so I did, I started praying more regularly, made duas and requested Allah to make my hair healthy and skin clear like before with the hope that Allah will help me. It’s been six months now and there is no change but feel my condition is not getting better but worse.
I know that Allah doesn’t like when one loses hope in Him and I strongly believe that you should never lose hope in Allah because ultimately Allah does support His followers. However, considering my current situation, I hate to say but at some point, I cry and start to lose hope because I think that when a muslim makes duas and Allah doesn’t grant him, it means He has something better planned for him. But in my case, I am just asking Allah to make my hair normal as they used to be and not make me go bald then what better there could be for myself and for my hair if Allah is not granting my wish. I have started to feel helpless and I ask Allah that I haven’t wished for something that is bad or anything, living with baldness will make my life hell and I will not want to live anymore. Of course, I’m only human, a woman and I can only tolerate to a certain level.
I feel too depressed becauss of thinking that I have only asked my hair back but Allah might never grant my wish because all I can see is progressive hair loss with no sign of healing.
I know people might think that why is she depressed over such a small thing but trust me these things could cause extreme Mental Health issues and low self-esteem that a person could forget to smile or lose hope to breathe. The more heartbreaking thing for me is that I have seeked Allah’s help and had such strong belief that only Allah can help me but no one else. But I am just losing hope and feel so depressed.
Can anyone please advise me what to do and how to connect more with Allah so He could help me and I don’t lose hope. Jazak Allah Khair for taking the time to read this and I would appreciate your kind response.

I can't tell about the religious aspects but did you change your diet recently? Are your fingernails still growing normally? Are you eating a healthy portion of meat, rice and potatoes? (The last two are rich in essential compounds that are required for hair). Don't answer me about that but tell your doctor.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam.

We are not clairvoyant and hence can not tell you why Allah is doing something. Questions on personal advice are off-topic. Make dua but also utilize the means through which Allah gives healing such as consulting a specialist doctors like a dermatologist and an endocrinologist. If one doctor does not suggest any treatment or their treatment does not produce results for a long time then consult other doctors.

Wishing for health an beauty is not a little wish. Look around you. Are all those people you see healthy or beautiful? Or do you only look at the healthy and beautiful? What if it is a reminder to look at the heart rather than the body?

Let's breakdown the question -

Why is Allah not responding?

Probable answers-
A) Test of your patience.
B) According to him it isn't good for you
C) You will get your wish but after a delay.
D) If nothing happens at all then you will be rewarded for it in hereafter.

I beleive in Allah more than science.

While that is a must, ask yourself if you are hungry and you pray for food will it drop from air (try it) or if you have to visit a beach but don't have money and ask Allah to transport you to there, will it happen? Almost no.
Because he himself says, he won't change a person's state until he cahnges himself. He has given you brain and hands and foot so use them.
Just like for passing exam along with dua you have to earn the knowledge too, similarly for your cure you hve to seek halal remedies along with dua and that included purchasing oil, medicines or visiting an expert in that field.
May Allah cure you soon.
